# Property of first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with following exercise:

Let $f$ be real function in $R$ of class $C^1$ and $f(r)=r$. Show that if $f'(r) \lt 1$ then no solution of the equation $x'=f(x/t)$ is tangent at $0$ to solution $x(t)=rt$.

Comment: As written the differential equation doesn't make sense near $t=0$, nor is $x(t)=r\ t$ a solution for $t>0$.